# Problem with GitHub Actions building and pushing Docker image

Tags: docker, github-actions

I had a script previously working from Docker Hub that I now want to run that pulls from GitHub Container registry instead. I'm sure I've got the syntax wrong somehow. I keep going between errors like "can not have using and with" to now, I'm getting a syntax error reporting on link 41 with no error (41 is the third line below).

I basically want to build my Docker image, then push it when my action file changes.

```yaml
        - name: Run step if any of the listed files above change    # UPDATE
        if: steps.changed-files-specific.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
          - uses: docker/login-action@v1
            with:
              registry: ghcr.io
              username: ${{ github.actor }}
              password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          - run: |
            RELEASEVERSION=11.09
            # RELEASEVERSION=$(cat version.txt)
            # https://github.community/t/wanting-to-add-a-build-date-and-time-to-my-github-action/220185/6'
            #
            RELEASEDATE1=$(date +"%m/%d/%YT%H:%M:%S%p")
            RELEASEDATE=$(TZ=":US/Pacific" date +%c)
            # https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164826/date-command-iso-8601-option
            RELEASEDATEISO=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
            #
            # removes any previous lines that might have contained VERSION or DATE (not tested)
            perl -ni -e 'next if /^RELEASE(?:VERSION|DATE)=/;print' .env.production
            # record in `.env.production`
            (
            echo "RELEASEVERSION=$RELEASEVERSION"
            echo "RELEASEDATE=$RELEASEDATE"
            echo "RELEASEDATEISO=$RELEASEDATEISO"
            ) >> .env.production
            echo "Docker webdevsvcc changed so building then pushing..."
            docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ghcr.io/pkellner/svccwebsitedev --tag ghcr.io/pkellner/svccwebsitedev:$RELEASEVERSION
            docker push ghcr.io/pkellner/svccwebsitedev --all-tags
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you _intended_ that to do, but it's not valid syntax for YAML generally or a [GitHub Actions workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) specifically. A job's `steps` should be an _array_ where each element is an _object_ that represents a step. And what are you trying to do with a `.env.production` file - the point of `dotenv` is generally _for development_ to replace the fact that in production you have _an actual environment_. The container should be portable _between_ environments.

Comment: My goal:  if action file changes, make minor updates for build; build docker image; then push image to ghcr.io

Comment: There's guidance to YAML syntax generally linked from the top of those docs. A [mre] would be helpful but the error's probably not _"can not have using and with"_ (because it's `uses` and you absolutely _can_ and sometimes _must_ have it with `with`, see the linked examples) but that you can't have `uses` and _`run`_ in the same step - what you have there is at least _two_ steps.

Comment: The indentation looks wrong, make sure the question matches your actual file.

Answer (score 0):

I watched a good video on Yaml and that helped a lot. Here is the file that I wanted that works now.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  # windows-latest | macos-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ApolloServerSvcc   # UPDATE

    name: docker build and push
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # setup Docker buld action
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        id: buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - name: Login to Github Packages
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
      - name: Image digest
          echo "One or more files in /ApolloServerSvcc changed in branch webdevsvccmobi-release"
        run: |
          RELEASEVERSION=11.02
          # RELEASEVERSION=$(cat version.txt)
          # https://github.community/t/wanting-to-add-a-build-date-and-time-to-my-github-action/220185/6'
          #
          RELEASEDATE1=$(date +"%m/%d/%YT%H:%M:%S%p")
          RELEASEDATE=$(TZ=":US/Pacific" date +%c)
          # https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164826/date-command-iso-8601-option
          RELEASEDATEISO=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
          #
          # removes any previous lines that might have contained VERSION or DATE (not tested)
          perl -ni -e 'next if /^RELEASE(?:VERSION|DATE)=/;print' .env.production
          # record in `.env`
          (
          echo "RELEASEVERSION=$RELEASEVERSION" 
          echo "RELEASEDATE=$RELEASEDATE"
          echo "RELEASEDATEISO=$RELEASEDATEISO"
          ) >> .env
          echo "building then pushing..."
          docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ghcr.io/pkellner/apolloserversvccdev:latest --tag ghcr.io/pkellner/apolloserversvccdev:$RELEASEVERSION
          docker push ghcr.io/pkellner/apolloserversvccdev --all-tags
```

Comment: Can you link to the video that helped?